# Trim white space in sql oracle query

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT   MT940_INFLOW.SEQ_NO, MT940_INFLOW.VALUE_DATE, MT940_INFLOW.POST_DATE, MT940_INFLOW.AMOUNT, MT940_INFLOW.DR_CR, MT940_INFLOW.REFERENCE, MT940_INFLOW.TRXN_TYPE, MT103_INFLOW.REFERENCE AS EXPR1, MT103_INFLOW.BENEFICIARY_CUSTOMER, MT103_INFLOW.RECEIVER_INFORMATION

FROM     MT940_INFLOW, MT103_INFLOW

WHERE    MT940_INFLOW.REFERENCE = MT103_INFLOW.REFERENCE
```

am joining 2 oracle tables as shown in my query above. My problem is that Reference column on table MT103_INFLOW, returns with whitespace> How can I modify my query to strip Reference column of MT103_INFLOW of the whitespace at the end of the reference.

Comment: this not it?http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the `trim` function:

```
SELECT trim(MT940_INFLOW.REFERENCE) AS REFERENCE, ....
WHERE    trim(MT940_INFLOW.REFERENCE) = trim(MT103_INFLOW.REFERENCE)
```

Note I added an alias, so the field will still be called `REFERENCE` in the result, but this alias cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Also, I think it would be better to filter out the spaces when storing the references, especially in your case, since you also use the reference for filtering. When you use functions like `trim` in the filter, you prevent Oracle from using any indexes on that column, so in the end the query will be slower. Therefor, it would be better to actually trim the spaces from the field when you store them.

To update existing data, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE MT940_INFLOW
SET REFERENCE = trim(REFERENCE);
```

When you have fixed input and existing data, you can remove the trim function from the `SELECT` query, and it will become more efficient.

Comment: It's worth noting certain data types will have spaces appended to them to fill the column definition (eg, if you have a `CHAR(10)` column, `'test'` is actually stored as `'test      '`)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.SEQ_NO, A.VALUE_DATE, A.POST_DATE, A.AMOUNT, A.DR_CR, REPLACE(A.REFERENCE,CHR(13)),
A.TRXN_TYPE, B.* FROM MT940_INFLOW A 
INNER JOIN MT103_INFLOW B 
ON A.REFERENCE = REPLACE(B.REFERENCE,CHR(13))
```

On further investigation, I noticed it was more of an extra line, as opposed to white space, so I modified my query as seen above and it worked fine.